# Can unbind be used for every type of binding?

Tags: jquery

AS I understand there are several way to bind an event to element i.e

1. bind
2. delegate
3. on
4. live

I understand that they have different purpose. I as able to find two functions that are opposite and used to remove the binding

1. unbind
2. undelegate

As I understand probably **undelegate** will be used to remove binding done with delegate method. The question I have:

Is there an equivalent of undelegate for **on**/**live** function or **unbind** is universal and can be used irrespective of how the binding was done (including delegate)?

Comment: [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is the new method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same functioning but they are changed according to the jquery versions. And the latest one is the [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and all others are depricated.

As per your question here is the binding and unbinding methods:

[bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) ------> [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) ------> [undelegate](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/)

[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) -------------> [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) -----------> [die](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

---

Suggestion: use on/off method.

Answer (score 0):

`.bind`, `.live` and `.delegate` have been deprecated. You should only be using `.on`.

However, the "opposite" methods for `.on` and `.live` are [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [`.die`](http://api.jquery.com/die/).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.on` and `.off` for ALL your event handling. `.on` can do everything `.bind`, `.delegate` and `.live` can do.